# Check if multiple key-value pairs exist in a Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following Ruby hash key-value pairs:

```
[
   {
      "trait_type"=>"Status", 
      "value"=>"Unbuilt", 
      "display_type"=>nil, 
      "max_value"=>nil, 
      "trait_count"=>4866, 
      "order"=>nil
   }
]
```

What I need to check is see if the following key-value pairs are **both** present:

```
{
   "value"=>"Unbuilt", 
   "trait_type"=>"Status"
}
```

Essentially wanting something to the effect of...

```
traits = [{"trait_type"=>"Status", "value"=>"Unbuilt", "display_type"=>nil, "max_value"=>nil, "trait_count"=>4866, "order"=>nil}]
filter_traits = {"value"=>"Unbuilt", "trait_type"=>"Status"}

traits.include? filter_traits
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using ruby >= 2.3, there is a fancy new `Hash >= Hash` operation that is conceptually similiar to a hypothetical `contains?`

Using your `traits` array:

```
trait = traits[0]
trait >= {"trait_type" => "Status", "value" => "Unbuilt"}
# => true

trait >= {"trait_type" => "Status", "value" => "Built"}
# => false
```

So you could try something like:

```
traits.select{|trait|
  trait >= filter_traits
}.length > 0
# => true
```

Comment: Good to know about [Hash#>=](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-3E-3D), a perfect fit for this problem.

Comment: While this is absolutely great answer, I really wonder what is the justification for existence of that operator and how does it translate onto mathematical comparison. IMO it's yet another operator that will make the code more cryptic, like Class comparison...

Comment: @BroiSatse tbh I agree and would have preferred it to be named `contains?`; there's a rubytalk thread about it iirc

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [
   {
      "trait_type"=>"Status", 
      "value"=>"Unbuilt", 
      "display_type"=>nil, 
      "max_value"=>nil, 
      "trait_count"=>4866, 
      "order"=>nil
   }
]
```

```
h1 = { "value"=>"Unbuilt", "trait_type"=>"Status" }
h2 = { "value"=>"Rebuilt", "trait_type"=>"Status" }
```

Here are three solutions.

```
arr[0].slice(*h1.keys) == h1
  #=> true
arr[0].slice(*h2.keys) == h2
  #=> false
```

---

```
arr[0].values_at(h1.keys) == h1.values
  #=> true
arr[0].values_at(h2.keys) == h2.values
  #=> false
```

---

```
arr[0] == arr[0].merge(h1)
  #=> true
arr[0] == arr[0].merge(h2)
  #=> false
```

Comment: Some other good option to consider as usual but I think its worth noting that these all take between 3 and 5 times as long to execute as the ```>=``` method and approx. twice as long as the ```all?``` method.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote that ```slice``` approach correctly?

Comment: I believe so: `arr[0].slice(*h1.keys) #=> {"value"=>"Unbuilt", "trait_type"=>"Status"}` and the same for `*h2.keys`. Do you see a problem?

Comment: I haven't studied what you're doing there, but during a quick benchmark test I got the following error:  ```NoMethodError: undefined method `slice' for #<Hash:0x0002971646ae38>```

Comment: @Michael, [Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice) made its debut in Ruby v2.5. I suspect you are using an older version.

Comment: Ah, yes.  That would be it.  Both the online version I use and the version I work with are 2.4x

Answer (score 1):

We also have the aptly named `all?` and `any?` methods that should do exactly what you're looking for in a very logical way.

All we need to do is loop through your `filter_traits` hash and test to see if all (or any) those `key:value` pairs are equal to (`==`) any corresponding key:value pairs inside your `traits` array:

```
traits = [{"trait_type"=>"Status", "value"=>"Unbuilt", "display_type"=>nil, "max_value"=>nil, "trait_count"=>4866, "order"=>nil}]
filter_traits = {"value"=>"Unbuilt", "trait_type"=>"Status"}

filter_traits.all? {|k, v| filter_traits[k] == traits[0][k]}
#=>  true

filter_traits = {"value"=>"Built", "trait_type"=>"Status"}
filter_traits.all? {|k, v| filter_traits[k] == traits[0][k]}
#=>  false

filter_traits.any? {|k, v| filter_traits[k] == traits[0][k]}
#=>  true
```

Comment: BY the way, this approach takes around twice as long to execute as does the ```>=``` method suggested by @jaimew.